# JFreeChart not rescaling

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have generated a custom Data Set which I then pass to a factory method of JFreeChart to get a charting component. Further I wrap it in a panel and place it in the main UI part of the application. I have set of filters which select specific series to be visible. I process this using standard renderer's method setSeriesVisible. Unfortunately, both axes do not rescale on teh chart after hiding the series. Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Please delete this duplicate of [*CombinedDomainXYPlot not rescaling domain axis*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870416/combineddomainxyplot-not-rescaling-domain-axis) and refrain from posting duplicates of your own questions.

Comment: This was a separate, general case. whish turned ouit to have been a library issue.

Comment: Why not post an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/163188) explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANswering my own question:

It was alibrary issue, resolved in 1.0.13+ versions