# CombinedDomainXYPlot - does range panning work at all?

Tags: charts, jfreechart, panning

I've created CombinedDomainXYPlot and added a bunch of XYPlots there.

Everything seems to be working as expected except vertical panning (move chart using mouse along with Y axis).
Domain panning (along X axis) works fine.

I've set both

1. combinedPlot.setDomainPannable(true);
2. combinedPlot.setRangePannable(true);

and also called setMouseWheelEnabled(true) on instance of ChartPanel;

Does anybody know if the range panning works at all?
And if yes, could you please give some example how to turn it on properly?

Just in case - running under JFreeChart 1.0.14, JDK 6, MacOS 10.8.

Thanks,
Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same result using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513). It's not documented explicitly, but it makes sense. Empirically, only the combined (shared) axis supports panning, even if the subplots would otherwise support panning on the orthogonal (independent) axis:

- [`CombinedDomainXYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html) supports *domain* panning; invokes `setFixedRangeAxisSpaceForSubplots()` in [`draw()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html#line.426).
- [`CombinedRangeXYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedRangeXYPlot.html) supports *range* panning; invokes `setFixedDomainAxisSpaceForSubplots()` in [`draw()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedRangeXYPlot.html#line.372).

Comment: Thanks, now it is much more clear. I hope, someday, both at the same time will be supported for the combined plot..