# How to deal with 2 TimeSerieses with the exact values?

Tags: jfreechart

I'm creating a `TimeSeries` chart with 2 `TimeSeries`es in it (i.e. A `Dataset` holding 2 `TimeSeries` objects.

It happens that both `TimeSeries` objects holds the same exact values and they are simply overlapping but that's not clear to the client as he only sees the result color or mixing the colors of both `TimeSeries` objects !

So he's seeing that the chart is displaying 2 sets of data, while only one line is drawn !

Is their a build-in way to deal with that ? How would you fix that ?

Personally I'm thinking of splitting this chart into 2 for it to be clear to the customer but I'm wondering if there is a way with less effort\more efficient to solve this situation.

**EDIT:** Final output should be images so this isn't a desktop application (i.e. Swing)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to let the user control series visibility using a suitable `Action`, a shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to detect the overlap automatically ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: You could traverse the series in pairs looking for values differing by suitable some _epsilon_. Also consider `ChartPanel#setMouseWheelEnabled(true)`.

Comment: Well I'm outputting images so there is not interaction with the client. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean like a PDF? I guess you could put each series in its own subplot of a combined plot.

Comment: No it's on a webpage actually but I guess it doesn't differ much if it's an image exported to a PDF or through web. By `subplot` I understand you are referring to the example you pointed at through a link in your example, or is it something else ?

Comment: Yes. On a web page, you can have limited interactivity by passing the state of an HTML checkbox as a parameter to your chart servlet. Sorry, I don't have an example.