# JFreeChart setRangeZeroBaseline visible

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to draw data points, and some of them include zero point.

As I know, by default, `JFreeChart` does not draw zero points (e.g. `(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)` do not show up in a graph).

I have tried setting

```
plot.setDomainZeroBaselineVisible(true);
plot.setRangeZeroBaselineVisible(true);
```

But I still cannot see the zero points.

Does anyone know how to show it?

p.s. Unfortunately, I cannot upload the screenshot. It is blocked...

Comment: `JFreeChart` shows zero points perfectly well, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513). Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Yes, I know that it works if the graph has negative points as well. But it does not show zero points when it has only positive points (I mean Y point).

Comment: Absent a screenshot, your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) should be sufficient.

Comment: Solved it. Reference this page. http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116563&sid=20357169f61a0fe07134892b75238331