# How to show only selected category's values on JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swt, jfreechart

Is it possible to show only the selected category's values on JFreeChart?

[chart http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8329/2npa.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8329/2npa.png)

For example, I have three categories on above picture and I want to give user to a selection option to see only selected category's value.

This is my JFreeChart creation code:

```
    lineDataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("", "Mesafe", "Seviye", lineDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    plot = (XYPlot) result.getPlot();
    ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setAutoRange(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting renderer from plot gives us a chance to setVisibility of series by

```
renderer = plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesVisible(int indexOfSeries, Boolean isSelected);
```

Create checkBoxes for each series and adding Selection or Action listener to these checkbox is  great way for this interaction between chart and user.

for SWT:

```
        Button btnCheckButton = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
        btnCheckButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if(btnCheckButton.getSelection()) {
                    setSeriesVisibility((Integer)btnCheckButton.getData(seriesName), true);
                } else {
                    setSeriesVisibility((Integer)btnCheckButton.getData(seriesName), false);
                }
            }
        });
        btnCheckButton.setText(seriesName);
        btnCheckButton.setData(seriesName, index);
        btnCheckButton.setSelection(true);
```

And this is setter function

```
public void setSeriesVisibility(int i, boolean isSelected) {
    renderer.setSeriesVisible(i, isSelected);
}
```

Comment: Good to know this works with SWT; a complete Swing example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513).