# Java JFreeChart - how to add the button to the left of the name of graphics?

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to add the button to the left of the name of graphics in that area marked by red color?

[image]

```
    chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(false);
    chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(false);
    chartPanel.setPopupMenu(null);
    frame = new JFrame(Title);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(chartPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To facilitate use on a [headless](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1012) server, a `JFreeChart` is *not* a Swing `JComponent`. The typical Swing approach is to enclose the chart in a `ChartPanel` and add the panel to a suitable [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Add controls to to an adjacent panel, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513) using `BorderLayout.SOUTH`.