# ComboBox selection

Tags: combobox, jfreechart

I have a graph showing the lines in 3 colours (red, green, blue), like screenshot.

When I press one of the colours, i.e. red, I want to show graph with only red colour. And if I press green then only green. But if I press nothing then it should show all.

Below my code for creating and drawing the lines.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.io.*; 

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;

class LineGraph extends ApplicationFrame {



       private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {

            // Graph wird erstellt...

       final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("","X","Y",dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,false,false);


            final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

            plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
            plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
            plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

            NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
            xAxis.setRange (0, 7500);

            NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
            yAxis.setRange(0, 270);


            return chart;


          }   





    public LineGraph(final String title) {

        super(title);
    }

   public ChartPanel createPanel(final String title){

       final XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
       final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
       ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
       chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(950, 570));
       //chartPanel.setSize(50, 50);
       //setContentPane(chartPanel);

       return chartPanel;
   }

   private XYSeriesCollection createDataset() {

       try {

       final int pictureWidth = 7500;
       final int pictureHeight = 5;
       int pictureArray[] = new int[pictureWidth * pictureHeight];
       int pixArray[] = new int[pictureWidth];
       int R, G, B, U;
       int averageX, averageY;

      FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("d:\\DO_18-02-2014_19-59-05-756_00010.img");

       int k = 0;

       XYSeries RED = new XYSeries("R");   
       XYSeries GREEN = new XYSeries("G");  
       XYSeries BLUE = new XYSeries("B");
       XYSeries  UNDEFINED = new XYSeries("U");


       for (int j = 0; j < pictureHeight; j++) 
        {for (int i = 0; i < pictureWidth; i++) 
           {   R = inp.read();
               G = inp.read();
               B = inp.read();
               U = inp.read();
               Color c = new Color(R, G, B, U);
               pictureArray[k++] = c.getRGB();

               System.out.println((new Integer(i)).toString()+" "+(new Integer(j)).toString());

               RED.add(i, R);
               GREEN.add(i, B);
               BLUE.add(i, G);
               UNDEFINED.add(i, U);

           }
       }
       inp.close();

       final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
       dataset.addSeries(RED);
       dataset.addSeries(GREEN);
       dataset.addSeries(BLUE);
       dataset.addSeries(UNDEFINED);

       return dataset;
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Exception Raised",
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           return null;
       }

   }   



    }
```

And below the code for the combobox.

```
![//Create ComboBox for RGB Choice
String ChannelStrings\[\] = { "All", "Red", "Green", "Blue"};
JComboBox ChannelChoice = new JComboBox(ChannelStrings);
ChannelChoice.setFont((new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13)));
panelButton.add(ChannelChoice);][1]
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to you screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513), you can control the visibility of individual series using the renderer's `setSeriesVisible()` method. The example cited uses checkboxes for control, but your combo's action listener can invoke the same method. [`ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1985) uses an instance of `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`; you can get a reference from the chart's plot, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.
Could you also give me some hints how to place this into my code?

Comment: The `setSeriesVisible()` call goes in your combo's action listener; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your revised approach; in your example, access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513)..

Comment: Thx for the hint. But I still do not know how to implement the setSeriesVisible() into my code. Could you please help. I really need your help.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck. Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I place a further code in here? I already put my code on top of this query.