# convert String to Dataset

Tags: java, dataset, jfreechart, linechart

I'm not sure if this is possible but here we go. Is there a way to convert a string to a Dataset? Let me explain. I have a list of persons that i need to represent on a JFreeChart line-chart and I therefore need to create a dataset for each person. Can I create datasets (possibly named after each person) for each person that is in the list? Something like this...

```
public XYDataset createDatasets(List<String> personList) {
    XYSeriesCollection seriesColletion = new XYSeriesCollection();
    for(String person : personList) {
        XYSeries person = new XYSeries(person);
        seriesColletion.addseries(person);
    }
return seriesColletion;
}
```

Or is there a smarter, better way of going about it? I'm sure this code doesn't work (particularly lines 3-6) but i'm only using it to better explain this.

Comment: You'll have to parse the values out of the `String`, but you can add multiple series, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513).

Comment: Great. This has indeed fixed it. Much appreciated help @trashgod.

Comment: Excellent; I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct approach is to parse the values out of the `String` and create an `XYSeries` for each person. Then you can add multiple series to an `XYSeriesCollection`, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513).

> Is there a smarter, better way of going about it?

Much depends on your application's data model. Assuming that you maintain a `List<Person>`, let each `Person` manage his or her own data internally; provide a convenience method that returns an `XYSeries` on demand, e.g.

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(…);
…
public XYDataset createDatasets(List<String> personList) {
    XYSeriesCollection seriesColletion = new XYSeriesCollection();
    for (Person person : personList) {
        seriesColletion.addseries(person.getXYSeries());
    }
    return seriesColletion;
}
```