# How to draw a spiderchart above a existing JfreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jfreechart

I have one a jfree chart which I can generate everytime I run the code.
Now i want to override few more spider graphs on the same chart. please help me how to do that

[image]

Above this i need to add one more spider chart using jfree.

Here is my code for doing this chart.

```
package com.rectrix.exide.pdfbox;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.PaintContext;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.SpiderWebPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.title.LegendTitle;
import org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.*;

public class DemoChart extends ApplicationFrame {

    public DemoChart(String s)
    {
        super(s);
        JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(jpanel);
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset()
    {


        String s1 = "First";
        String s2 = "Second";
        String s3 = "Third";
        String s4 = "Forth";
        String s5 = "Fivth";
        String s6 = "Sixth";
        String s7 = "Seventh";
        String s8 = "Eighth";
        String s9 = "Ninth";
        String s10 = "Tenth";

        DefaultCategoryDataset defaultcategorydataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        int count = 5;
        int value = 0;
        //String keyRow="s";
        for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            value = i*4;
            Comparable colKey = 0;
            String keyRow = "s"+i;
            for(int j=1;j<=count;j++){
            colKey = j;
                defaultcategorydataset.addValue(value, keyRow, colKey);
            }
        }
return defaultcategorydataset;
    }

    public static JFreeChart createChart1(CategoryDataset categorydataset,double d) {
        SpiderWebPlot plot = new SpiderWebPlot(categorydataset);
        Color bckColor1 = Color.decode("#4282CE"); //Light blue
        Paint p = new GradientPaint(0, 1, bckColor1, 0, 1, bckColor1);
        plot.setSeriesPaint(p);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", plot);
        return chart;
    }


    public static JPanel createDemoPanel()
    {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart1(createDataset(), 10D);
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DemoChart spiderwebchartdemo1 = new DemoChart("JFreeChart: SpiderWebChartDemo1.java");
        spiderwebchartdemo1.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(spiderwebchartdemo1);
        spiderwebchartdemo1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Please help me as soon as possible i need to send this build by tomorrow
Thank u in advance for helping and taking efforts to see this.

Comment: I see 10 series in your plot; why can't you add an 11th?

Comment: If I do 11th series i would only get another star kind of graph outside the last existing graph. But what I need is, I want to show a graph of different reading above these 10 series star graph that i have now drawn.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to override few more spider graphs on the same chart.

It may help to examine how a [spider web plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) is used to display multivariate data. The simplified example below compares just two `OBSERVATIONS`, each having five `VARIABLES` named `A .. E`, with random values in the range `1 .. 3`. By chance, the values for variable `B` coincide; the rest differ. You can adjust the value of `OBSERVATIONS` to see the effect, but the result becomes progressively more muddled as the number of observations grows. You may want to alter series visibility, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513), or consider these [alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart#Alternatives).

[image: spider web plot]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.SpiderWebPlot;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32885067/230513 */
public class SpiderChart extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final int OBSERVATIONS = 2;
    private static final int VARIABLES = 5;
    private static final Random r = new Random();

    public SpiderChart(String s) {
        super(s);
        add(createDemoPanel());
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for (int i = 1; i <= OBSERVATIONS; i++) {
            String rowKey = "Observation " + i;
            for (int j = 1; j <= VARIABLES; j++) {
                Comparable colKey = Character.valueOf((char)(j+64));
                dataset.addValue(r.nextInt(3) + 1, rowKey, colKey);
            }
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    public static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
        SpiderWebPlot plot = new SpiderWebPlot(dataset);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Test", plot);
        return chart;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            SpiderChart demo = new SpiderChart("SpiderWebChart");
            demo.pack();
            demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            demo.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```