# Java how to create radar chart like on photo

Tags: java, jfreechart

Can someone help me with creating radar chart like the one below? 
I only know how to create a simple radar chart, but I need one that's looks exactly like this:

[image: Skill radar chart]

Comment: That's a bit broad, don't you think? It's not one of the built-in charts so you would need to do a lot of work. You may want to hire somebody (like the people who created JFreeChart)

Comment: You might start with a `SpiderWebPlot`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32885067/230513).

Comment: It's chart from Excel and this three-coloured board it's another shape.

Comment: Save it as jpg and load it in java... (then it will be exactly the same) ; )

Comment: But this is a skill radar chart based on table, so I have to manipulate data on it