# JFreeChart Polar chart custom X labels

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I would like to customize my PolarChart to replace the angle values displayed in a PolarChart by default
[image]
, with custom strings like this :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`refreshAngleTicks()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PolarPlot.html#refreshAngleTicks--) method of [`PolarPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PolarPlot.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3458824/230513):

```
import static org.jfree.ui.TextAnchor.*
…
PolarPlot plot = new PolarPlot() {

    @Override
    protected List refreshAngleTicks() {
        List ticks = new ArrayList();
        ticks.add(new NumberTick(0, "maxCharTick: 20", TOP_LEFT, TOP_LEFT, 0));
        ticks.add(new NumberTick(45, "energyComsuption: 1", TOP_LEFT, TOP_LEFT, 0));
        ticks.add(new NumberTick(90, "maxDamage: 40", TOP_LEFT, TOP_LEFT, 0));
        …
        return ticks;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, consider a [`SpiderWebPlot`](http://jfreechart%20spiderwebplot), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32885067/230513).

Comment: I didn't see there was a SpiderWebPlot class in the library. Thank you for the information